# Does std::remove_if call the destructor?

Tags: c++

I'm using `std::remove_if` to move a selection of `std::vector` elements to the end so that I can copy them to another vector then erase the range:

```
using ElemPtr = std::shared_ptr<Elem>;
auto iter = std::remove_if(source.begin(),source.end(), [&](const ElemPtr& e){ /* ... */ });
dest.insert(dest.end(),iter,source.end());
source.erase(iter,source.end());
```

What happens is that after the call to `std::remove_if`, the values to be removed have their destructor called (ie. they are set to null). I end up just copying a bunch of null pointers, which isn't great.

Resources like cppreference.com do not have any mention of this behaviour so I am wondering if this is a compiler bug?

I am using gcc 5.2.0.

Comment: Looks like you might want `std::partition` or `stable_partition`

Comment: @ZanLynx - calling erase on pointers does **not** delete the pointed-to objects; it calls the destructor, which, for pointers, doesn't do anything. However, the elements here are `std::shared_ptr`, so erase might end up deleting the object, depending on whether there are other `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` objects pointing to it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`std::remove_if` does **not** move elements to be removed to the end. Instead, it moves elements **not** to be removed to the front; the contents of the tail are left unspecified.

In the process, some elements that the predicate says should be removed may be overwritten by (to be precise, assigned from) other elements. For an element that's a `shared_ptr`, this means it may very well destroy the underlying object.

What you seem to be looking for is `std::partition`. It behaves exactly the way you seem to expect `std::remove_if` to behave.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug. In fact, they're not destructor called, they're just moved. Their dtor won't be called until container's `erase` get called.

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) mentioned that,

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have **unspecified values (as per MoveAssignable post-condition)**. A call to remove is typically followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove_if` move assigns the iterator values **not** satisfying the given unary predicate (if they originally appear after at least one iterator value satisfying the given unary predicate). No destructors will be called.

## Possible implementation of `std::remove_if`

```
template< typename ForwardIt, typename UnaryPredicate >
ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p) {
    first = std::find_if(first, last, p);
    if (first != last)
        for (ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last;)
            if (!p(*i))
                *first++ = std::move(*i); // Move assignment, no destructors called
    return first;
}
```

**Source**: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

## Illustration ([Erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom))

**Code** [[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t4P51WEUVgBfi4ZE)]:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    constexpr A(int a) noexcept : m_a(a) {}
    constexpr A(const A&) noexcept = default;
    constexpr A(A&&) noexcept = default;
    ~A() noexcept {
        std::cout << "Destruction: " << m_a << std::endl;
    }
    A& operator=(const A& a) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Copy assignment: " << a.m_a << std::endl;
        m_a = a.m_a;
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& a) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Move assignment: " << a.m_a << std::endl;
        m_a = a.m_a;
        return *this;
    }

    int m_a;
};


int main() {
    std::vector< A > v = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5 };
    std::cout << "BEGIN REMOVE" << std::endl;
    auto end = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const A& a) noexcept { return 5 == a.m_a; });
    std::cout << "BEGIN ERASE" << std::endl;
    v.erase(end, v.end());
    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Destruction: 5
Destruction: 5
Destruction: 4
Destruction: 5
Destruction: 2
Destruction: 1
BEGIN REMOVE
Move assignment: 4
BEGIN ERASE
Destruction: 4 // Could be garbage as well (unspecified, but valid, state)
Destruction: 5
Destruction: 5
END
Destruction: 1
Destruction: 2
Destruction: 4
```